# How to improve the following stored procedure to verify the syntax of an email?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_EMAIL
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL 
);
```

I would like to create a stored procedure to check if the syntax of a new email is ok, I just want to cover two possibilities if this email has not an "@" character as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_EMAIL (EMAIL)
VALUES ('email.com')
```

And also if this email has not a corresponding dot:

```
 INSERT INTO TBL_EMAIL (EMAIL)
 VALUES ('email@com')
```

I just want to cover these cases, create a stored procedure to be activated when there is an insert or update

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_Verify_Email
ON TBL_EMAIL
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
```

Declaring variables to count inside the while and some flag to know if the "@" is located at the first position,

```
    DECLARE @V_COUNT INT,@FLAG INT
    DECLARE @V_EMAIL_INSERTED VARCHAR(25)
    SET @V_COUNT = 1
    SET @FLAG = 0
    SELECT @V_EMAIL_INSERTED = EMAIL FROM INSERTED;

    WHILE(@V_COUNT < LEN(@V_EMAIL_INSERTED)) BEGIN
        IF(SUBSTRING(@V_EMAIL_INSERTED,@V_COUNT,1)='@' AND @V_COUNT > 4) BEGIN
            SET @FLAG = @FLAG + 1
        END
        SET @V_COUNT = @V_COUNT + 1 
    END
```

To rollback the transaction when the email has and "@" at the first position,

```
    IF(@FLAG <> 1) BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid Email',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END     
END
```

However this was my first approach but I understand that there is a lot of missing cases and invalid emails, thus I would like to appreciate suggestions to improve my logic and just allow emails with the appropriated structure I mean `user@something.com`, thanks for the support.

Comment: . . I fixed the tags.  With your reputation level, you should know to avoid incompatible database tags and to put the appropriate software on the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, and thanks for the fixes, I really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a trigger.  The correct way is a `check` constraint:

```
alter table tbl_email
    add constraint chk_email_email
        check (email like '%@%.%');
```

This will ensure data integrity for both inserts *and updates*.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful but I am practicing the usage of triggers, I would like to appreciate to use a trigger, thanks for the support.

Comment: For your trigger practice make sure you test Insert and Update and Delete scenarios.  Test updating multiple rows at once and make sure you have some rows you did not want to update in your test.  Also test with null values.  This will give you a better feel for your trigger skills.

Comment: @SqlSurfer, thanks for the suggestions, at this moment I am analyzing the DELETED and INSERTED tables,

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, Could you please tell me the meaning of: email like '%@%.%' that is a kind of regular expression?

Comment: @neo33, see the SQL Server Books Online LIKE reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks a lot for the information I finally realized that % means any string composed by zero or more characters.